# Android: How to return a context in a class from another class (getting an error at getContext())

Tags: java, android

Basically I want to play an alarm sound after the value `y` in the below class is exceeded.
I have this class where I have passed `Context` as a parameter:

```
public class Point {

  private Context context;
  private int x;
  private int y;

public Point( Context context, int x, int y)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    if(y>30000){
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, notification);
        mp.start();
    }
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

}
```

I don't really know how to return the `Context` in this class which has a method which returns the constructor `Point` in the above class(it calls the `Point` class) but here is what I tried :

```
public class UbidotsData {

 public static Point getDataFromReceiver(int x)
{
    ApiClient api = new ApiClient("A1E-0d8bec822d9d5ccae0fb08a75dfdb22e17c3");
    Variable ldr = api.getVariable("5a5f80eec03f971388983b8e");
    Value[] values = ldr.getValues();
    int newValue = (int) values[0].getValue();

    return new Point(Context.getContext,x, newValue); //error "cannot resolve symbol 'getContext'" occurs here
    }
}
```

This is the `Context.java` class:

```
public class Context extends Application {

 public static Context mcontext;

 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mcontext= (Context) getApplicationContext();
}
 public static Context getContext(){
    return mcontext;
   }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name= "com.example.teerna.smartagriculturev5.Context"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If i got your point, try to use `MainActivity.getContext()` instead of `Context.getContext()`

Comment: @FarBen  Still getting the same error when I did that

Comment: could you give us the message of error

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'getContext'

Comment: i mean you get the error in runtime or before?

Comment: check the import, probably you have `android.content.Context` instead of *your* Context (bad naming BTW) in UbidotsData

Comment: Before runtime. I just added these lines in the `UbidotsData. java` class:  `private static Context context; ` and `return new Point(context,x, newValue);` It fixed the error but haven't yet run it

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Yup, I have this `import android.content.Context;`. What should I import then?

Comment: you must initialise context after all.

Comment: @FarBen I don't get it.. How should I initialize it?

Comment: to make things more clear `public class MyContext extends Application`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I removed the `import android.content.Context;` and it's okay now. Thanks :)